# Beautiful Soup 4 code returns different answer for different situations

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage using the following BS4 code :

```
url = "http://www.xyz.con/abc.html"
#url2 = "file:///C:/Users/abc.html"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
myuls = soup.findAll("ul",{ "class" : "ctlg-holder"})
mya = myuls[0].findAll("a")
```

The problem is , the following code return 253 links on online page , but when i save the page in my computer and use local url2 , then it returns 342 links ( Correct )

Why does my code works for the locally saved page (url2) only ? why does'nt it return correct answer on http url?

Comment: Page can use javascipt in browser to generate extra data.

Comment: @furas : Is there any workaround ? I really dont care about JS part .

Answer (score 0):

Page can use javascipt in browser to generate extra data.

You can't get data with `urllib2` or `requests` because this tools doesn't run javascript.

You can use tools like `Selenium` which simulate browser and can run javascipt.

Or you have to analyze page in browser and find out how javascript get extra data.
Maybe you could download it with `urllib2` or `requests`. But extra data can be send as `JSON` and you will have to use module `json`.

Comment: then why would the offline page return correct answer?

Comment: maybe tools which you use to save page can save current state of DOM tree in its memory. Did you use browser to save it ?

Comment: There can be another reason, browser can send different page for "logged in" user, or user which have special `cookie` in browser memory, or user which use some kind of browser, etc.

Comment: The Website which i am scraping does'nt require user to login.

Comment: In web scraping problems the most usefull information is url. Without url we can't see how page works.